# How to segment and transcribe an audio from a video into timestamped segments?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, openai-api, automatic-speech-recognition

I want to segment a video transcript into chapters based on the content of each line of speech. The transcript would be used to generate a series of start and end timestamps for each chapter. This is similar to how YouTube now "auto-chapters" videos.

Example .srt transcript:

```
...

70
00:02:53,640 --> 00:02:54,760
All right, coming in at number five,

71
00:02:54,760 --> 00:02:57,640
we have another habit that saves me around 15 minutes a day
...
```

I have had minimal luck doing this with ChatGPT as it finds it difficult to both segment by topic and recollect start and end timestamps accurately. I am now exploring whether there are other options for doing this.

I know topic modeling based on time series is possible with some python libraries. I have also read about text tiling as another option. **What options are there for achieving an outcome like this?**

Note: The format above (.srt) is not necessary. It's just the idea that the input is a list of text-content with start and end timestamps.

Comment: See https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino_notebooks/blob/main/notebooks/227-whisper-subtitles-generation/227-whisper-subtitles-generation.ipynb

Answer (score 7):

First you might need to install these

```
! pip install -U mock pytube openai-whisper
```

## Pull a Youtube video down and extract the audio

```
import re
import mock

from pytube.cipher import get_throttling_function_code

def patched_throttling_plan(js: str):
    """Patch throttling plan, from https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1498"""
    raw_code = get_throttling_function_code(js)

    transform_start = r"try{"
    plan_regex = re.compile(transform_start)
    match = plan_regex.search(raw_code)

    #transform_plan_raw = find_object_from_startpoint(raw_code, match.span()[1] - 1)
    transform_plan_raw = js

    # Steps are either c[x](c[y]) or c[x](c[y],c[z])
    step_start = r"c\[(\d+)\]\(c\[(\d+)\](,c(\[(\d+)\]))?\)"
    step_regex = re.compile(step_start)
    matches = step_regex.findall(transform_plan_raw)
    transform_steps = []
    for match in matches:
        if match[4] != '':
            transform_steps.append((match[0],match[1],match[4]))
        else:
            transform_steps.append((match[0],match[1]))

    return transform_steps


with mock.patch('pytube.cipher.get_throttling_plan', patched_throttling_plan):
    from pytube import YouTube
    url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZBVrPWwSlRM'

    video = YouTube(url)
    audio = video.streams.filter(only_audio=True, file_extension='mp4')[0]
    audio.download(filename='team-rocket.mp4')
```

And if you would like to play it to make sure the audio is correct in Jupyter:

```
from IPython.display import Audio, display

display(Audio('team-rocket.mp4', autoplay=True))
```

## Transcribe the audio to text

```
import whisper

model = whisper.load_model("base")
result = model.transcribe('team-rocket.mp4')
print(result["text"])
```

[out]:

```
Prepare for trouble! Make it double! Super tip the world from devastation! To unite all peoples within our nation! To denounce the evils of truth and love! To extend our reach to the stars above! Jesse! James! Team Rocket blast off at the speed of life! So then to now, we're prepared to fight! Be out! That's right! Let's...
```

**Note:** The output of ASR is definitely not perfect but very much usable as a first draft that requires some manual post-edits. Please DO NOT submit the subs directly to your fav fan-subs forum, it'll surely fail the QC moderator.

## But how about the timestamps?

Then we need a little more sophistication than crudely pulling the audio and then doing Automatic Speech Recognition (ASR)

Here's a good article: https://blog.searce.com/generate-srt-file-subtitles-using-google-clouds-speech-to-text-api-402b2f1da3bd

And also we are blessed in today's age of AI... Tada: https://github.com/linto-ai/whisper-timestamped

```
! pip install -U git+https://github.com/linto-ai/whisper-timestamped
```

Then in code:

```
import whisper_timestamped as whisper

audio = whisper.load_audio('team-rocket.mp4')
model = whisper.load_model("base")

result = whisper.transcribe(model, audio, language="en")

import json
print(json.dumps(result, indent = 2, ensure_ascii = False))
```

[out]:

```
{
  "text": " Prepare for trouble! Make it double! Super tip the world from devastation! To unite all peoples within our nation! To denounce the evils of truth and love! To extend our reach to the stars above! Jesse! James! Team Rocket blast off at the speed of life! So then to now, we're prepared to fight! Be out! That's right! Let's...",
  "segments": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "seek": 0,
      "start": 0.22,
      "end": 1.66,
      "text": " Prepare for trouble!",
      "tokens": [
        50364,
        29689,
        337,
        5253,
        0,
        50464
      ],
      "temperature": 0.0,
      "avg_logprob": -0.24259458803663067,
      "compression_ratio": 1.5330188679245282,
      "no_speech_prob": 0.7252825498580933,
      "confidence": 0.873,
      "words": [
        {
          "text": "Prepare",
          "start": 0.22,
          "end": 0.68,
          "confidence": 0.726
        },
        {
          "text": "for",
          "start": 0.68,
          "end": 1.1,
          "confidence": 0.982
        },
        {
          "text": "trouble!",
          "start": 1.1,
          "end": 1.66,
          "confidence": 0.933
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "seek": 0,
      "start": 2.48,
      "end": 3.72,
      "text": " Make it double!",
      "tokens": [
        50464,
        4387,
        309,
        3834,
        0,
        50564
      ],
      "temperature": 0.0,
      "avg_logprob": -0.24259458803663067,
      "compression_ratio": 1.5330188679245282,
      "no_speech_prob": 0.7252825498580933,
      "confidence": 0.878,
      "words": [
        {
          "text": "Make",
          "start": 2.48,
          "end": 2.84,
          "confidence": 0.979
        },
        {
          "text": "it",
          "start": 2.84,
          "end": 3.12,
          "confidence": 0.995
        },
        {
          "text": "double!",
          "start": 3.12,
          "end": 3.72,
          "confidence": 0.694
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "seek": 0,
      "start": 4.2,
      "end": 6.06,
      "text": " Super tip the world from devastation!",
      "tokens": [
        50564,
        4548,
        4125,
        264,
        1002,
        490,
        13959,
        399,
        0,
        50664
      ],
      "temperature": 0.0,
      "avg_logprob": -0.24259458803663067,
      "compression_ratio": 1.5330188679245282,
      "no_speech_prob": 0.7252825498580933,
      "confidence": 0.709,
      "words": [
        {
          "text": "Super",
          "start": 4.2,
          "end": 4.44,
          "confidence": 0.728
        },
        {
          "text": "tip",
          "start": 4.44,
          "end": 4.66,
          "confidence": 0.195
        },
        {
          "text": "the",
          "start": 4.66,
          "end": 4.86,
          "confidence": 0.73
        },
        {
          "text": "world",
          "start": 4.86,
          "end": 5.12,
          "confidence": 0.913
        },
        {
          "text": "from",
          "start": 5.12,
          "end": 5.36,
          "confidence": 0.966
        },
        {
          "text": "devastation!",
          "start": 5.36,
          "end": 6.06,
          "confidence": 0.991
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "seek": 0,
      "start": 6.4,
      "end": 8.78,
      "text": " To unite all peoples within our nation!",
      "tokens": [
        50664,
        1407,
        29320,
        439,
        16915,
        1951,
        527,
        4790,
        0,
        50814
      ],
      "temperature": 0.0,
      "avg_logprob": -0.24259458803663067,
      "compression_ratio": 1.5330188679245282,
      "no_speech_prob": 0.7252825498580933,
      "confidence": 0.943,
      "words": [
        {
          "text": "To",
          "start": 6.4,
          "end": 6.52,
          "confidence": 0.772
        },
        {
          "text": "unite",
          "start": 6.52,
          "end": 6.88,
          "confidence": 0.991
        },
        {
          "text": "all",
          "start": 6.88,
          "end": 7.22,
          "confidence": 0.992
        },
        {
          "text": "peoples",
          "start": 7.22,
          "end": 7.64,
          "confidence": 0.941
        },
        {
          "text": "within",
          "start": 7.64,
          "end": 8.08,
          "confidence": 0.97
        },
        {
          "text": "our",
          "start": 8.08,
          "end": 8.28,
          "confidence": 0.995
        },
        {
          "text": "nation!",
          "start": 8.28,
          "end": 8.78,
          "confidence": 0.96
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "seek": 0,
      "start": 9.26,
      "end": 11.26,
      "text": " To denounce the evils of truth and love!",
      "tokens": [
        50814,
        1407,
        1441,
        7826,
        264,
        1073,
        4174,
        295,
        3494,
        293,
        959,
        0,
        50914
      ],
      "temperature": 0.0,
      "avg_logprob": -0.24259458803663067,
      "compression_ratio": 1.5330188679245282,
      "no_speech_prob": 0.7252825498580933,
      "confidence": 0.883,
      "words": [
        {
          "text": "To",
          "start": 9.26,
          "end": 9.44,
          "confidence": 0.684
        },
        {
          "text": "denounce",
          "start": 9.44,
          "end": 9.96,
          "confidence": 0.739
        },
        {
          "text": "the",
          "start": 9.96,
          "end": 10.14,
          "confidence": 0.988
        },
        {
          "text": "evils",
          "start": 10.14,
          "end": 10.44,
          "confidence": 0.942
        },
        {
          "text": "of",
          "start": 10.44,
          "end": 10.58,
          "confidence": 0.995
        },
        {
          "text": "truth",
          "start": 10.58,
          "end": 10.8,
          "confidence": 0.906
        },
        {
          "text": "and",
          "start": 10.8,
          "end": 11.02,
          "confidence": 0.986
        },
        {
          "text": "love!",
          "start": 11.02,
          "end": 11.26,
          "confidence": 0.987
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "seek": 0,
      "start": 11.44,
      "end": 13.22,
      "text": " To extend our reach to the stars above!",
      "tokens": [
        50914,
        1407,
        10101,
        527,
        2524,
        281,
        264,
        6105,
        3673,
        0,
        51014
      ],
      "temperature": 0.0,
      "avg_logprob": -0.24259458803663067,
      "compression_ratio": 1.5330188679245282,
      "no_speech_prob": 0.7252825498580933,
      "confidence": 0.992,
      "words": [
        {
          "text": "To",
          "start": 11.44,
          "end": 11.52,
          "confidence": 0.993
        },
        {
          "text": "extend",
          "start": 11.52,
          "end": 11.88,
          "confidence": 0.996
        },
        {
          "text": "our",
          "start": 11.88,
          "end": 12.1,
          "confidence": 0.989
        },
        {
          "text": "reach",
          "start": 12.1,
          "end": 12.32,
          "confidence": 0.988
        },
        {
          "text": "to",
          "start": 12.32,
          "end": 12.52,
          "confidence": 0.997
        },
        {
          "text": "the",
          "start": 12.52,
          "end": 12.62,
          "confidence": 0.993
        },
        {
          "text": "stars",
          "start": 12.62,
          "end": 12.86,
          "confidence": 0.988
        },
        {
          "text": "above!",
          "start": 12.86,
          "end": 13.22,
          "confidence": 0.993
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "seek": 0,
      "start": 13.48,
      "end": 14.16,
      "text": " Jesse!",
      "tokens": [
        51014,
        21895,
        0,
        51064
      ],
      "temperature": 0.0,
      "avg_logprob": -0.24259458803663067,
      "compression_ratio": 1.5330188679245282,
      "no_speech_prob": 0.7252825498580933,
      "confidence": 0.211,
      "words": [
        {
          "text": "Jesse!",
          "start": 13.48,
          "end": 14.16,
          "confidence": 0.211
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "seek": 0,
      "start": 14.48,
      "end": 15.22,
      "text": " James!",
      "tokens": [
        51064,
        5678,
        0,
        51114
      ],
      "temperature": 0.0,
      "avg_logprob": -0.24259458803663067,
      "compression_ratio": 1.5330188679245282,
      "no_speech_prob": 0.7252825498580933,
      "confidence": 0.874,
      "words": [
        {
          "text": "James!",
          "start": 14.48,
          "end": 15.22,
          "confidence": 0.874
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "seek": 0,
      "start": 15.48,
      "end": 18.42,
      "text": " Team Rocket blast off at the speed of life!",
      "tokens": [
        51114,
        7606,
        29651,
        12035,
        766,
        412,
        264,
        3073,
        295,
        993,
        0,
        51264
      ],
      "temperature": 0.0,
      "avg_logprob": -0.24259458803663067,
      "compression_ratio": 1.5330188679245282,
      "no_speech_prob": 0.7252825498580933,
      "confidence": 0.711,
      "words": [
        {
          "text": "Team",
          "start": 15.48,
          "end": 16.22,
          "confidence": 0.147
        },
        {
          "text": "Rocket",
          "start": 16.22,
          "end": 16.66,
          "confidence": 0.919
        },
        {
          "text": "blast",
          "start": 16.66,
          "end": 17.06,
          "confidence": 0.774
        },
        {
          "text": "off",
          "start": 17.06,
          "end": 17.36,
          "confidence": 0.722
        },
        {
          "text": "at",
          "start": 17.36,
          "end": 17.5,
          "confidence": 0.946
        },
        {
          "text": "the",
          "start": 17.5,
          "end": 17.62,
          "confidence": 0.993
        },
        {
          "text": "speed",
          "start": 17.62,
          "end": 17.96,
          "confidence": 0.983
        },
        {
          "text": "of",
          "start": 17.96,
          "end": 18.2,
          "confidence": 0.998
        },
        {
          "text": "life!",
          "start": 18.2,
          "end": 18.42,
          "confidence": 0.667
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "seek": 0,
      "start": 18.48,
      "end": 20.96,
      "text": " So then to now, we're prepared to fight!",
      "tokens": [
        51264,
        407,
        550,
        281,
        586,
        11,
        321,
        434,
        4927,
        281,
        2092,
        0,
        51414
      ],
      "temperature": 0.0,
      "avg_logprob": -0.24259458803663067,
      "compression_ratio": 1.5330188679245282,
      "no_speech_prob": 0.7252825498580933,
      "confidence": 0.79,
      "words": [
        {
          "text": "So",
          "start": 18.48,
          "end": 19.0,
          "confidence": 0.753
        },
        {
          "text": "then",
          "start": 19.0,
          "end": 19.18,
          "confidence": 0.564
        },
        {
          "text": "to",
          "start": 19.18,
          "end": 19.34,
          "confidence": 0.829
        },
        {
          "text": "now,",
          "start": 19.34,
          "end": 19.66,
          "confidence": 0.984
        },
        {
          "text": "we're",
          "start": 19.9,
          "end": 20.14,
          "confidence": 0.597
        },
        {
          "text": "prepared",
          "start": 20.14,
          "end": 20.3,
          "confidence": 0.973
        },
        {
          "text": "to",
          "start": 20.3,
          "end": 20.56,
          "confidence": 0.998
        },
        {
          "text": "fight!",
          "start": 20.56,
          "end": 20.96,
          "confidence": 0.996
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "seek": 0,
      "start": 21.1,
      "end": 23.28,
      "text": " Be out! That's right! Let's...",
      "tokens": [
        51414,
        879,
        484,
        0,
        663,
        311,
        558,
        0,
        961,
        311,
        485,
        51514
      ],
      "temperature": 0.0,
      "avg_logprob": -0.24259458803663067,
      "compression_ratio": 1.5330188679245282,
      "no_speech_prob": 0.7252825498580933,
      "confidence": 0.795,
      "words": [
        {
          "text": "Be",
          "start": 21.1,
          "end": 21.28,
          "confidence": 0.462
        },
        {
          "text": "out!",
          "start": 21.28,
          "end": 21.74,
          "confidence": 0.807
        },
        {
          "text": "That's",
          "start": 22.02,
          "end": 22.36,
          "confidence": 0.958
        },
        {
          "text": "right!",
          "start": 22.36,
          "end": 22.64,
          "confidence": 0.992
        },
        {
          "text": "Let's...",
          "start": 22.86,
          "end": 23.28,
          "confidence": 0.769
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "language": "en"
}
```

### You've gone so far with some fine-grained JSON and timestamps, how about some code to convert the JSON to .srt file?

```
for i, segment in enumerate(result['segments']):
  start, end = segment['start'], segment['end']
  print(i)
  print(f"00:00:{str(int(start)).replace('.', ',')} --> 00:00:{str(int(end)).replace('.', ',')}")
  print(segment['text'].strip())
  print()
```

[out]:

```
0
00:00:0 --> 00:00:1
Prepare for trouble!

1
00:00:2 --> 00:00:3
Make it double!

2
00:00:4 --> 00:00:6
Super tip the world from devastation!

3
00:00:6 --> 00:00:8
To unite all peoples within our nation!

4
00:00:9 --> 00:00:11
To denounce the evils of truth and love!

5
00:00:11 --> 00:00:13
To extend our reach to the stars above!

6
00:00:13 --> 00:00:14
Jesse!

7
00:00:14 --> 00:00:15
James!

8
00:00:15 --> 00:00:18
Team Rocket blast off at the speed of life!

9
00:00:18 --> 00:00:20
So then to now, we're prepared to fight!

10
00:00:21 --> 00:00:23
Be out! That's right! Let's...
```

#### 小等咧! (Wait a minute!), you've hard-coded the hours and minutes... What do I do for longer videos?

I'm sure with the JSON output from `whisper-timestamped` you can easily figure out the conversion. Hint: `from datetime import timedelta; str(timedelta(seconds=float(start)))`

Have fun munging the data to the desired format you need!